# Is there any way in OS X to switch between full screen windows on either a within-app or an MRU basis

Tags: macos

Once a window is made full-screen in OS X, it no longer seems to be available for switching to with Cmd-Backtick. If I make all the windows in an app full screen, Cmd-Tab to the app will take me to one of those windows (seemingly the first one opened) but it seems I then can't access the other windows belonging to that app via Cmd-Backtick. Instead, I have to use the "Window" menu in the app or laboriously cycle through all the spaces and full screen windows by swiping or Ctrl-Arrowing until I find the one I want.

Is there any way either to quickly cycle through the full screen windows belonging to a particular app or to go through all full screen windows in an MRU (most recently used) order instead of the fixed order that swiping and Ctrl-Arrowing gives you? I'd actually prefer the latter, but either would do.